# How do I perfom update function for eloquent in Laravel for 1 to many?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update status for id=3

[entry with id=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7WRc.png)

I'm getting error with

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'field
> list' (SQL: select `3` from `entry`)

```
   public function edit($id)
    {
        
        $entrys = Entry::with('user')->get($id);

        return view('entry.edit')->with('entry', $entrys);
    }
```

```
Route::get('/entry/edit{id}', 'EntryController@edit')->name('entry.edit')->middleware('is_admin');
Route::post('/entry/edit', 'EntryController@update')->name('entry.update')->middleware('is_admin');
```

```
class Entry extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'status',
        'file',
        'user_id'
    ];

  
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```
 public function entrys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Entry::class);
    }
```

Comment: add your `update()` function

Comment: i have updated my post

Comment: Please don't change your question after you've asked it and received relevant answers. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error fixes is

```php
 $entrys = Entry::with('user')->find($id);
```

don't pass value to `get()`

---

for update add `user_id` key i assume you want to insert `auth()->id()` so code is

```php
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [

            'status' => 'required',
        ]);

        $entrys = new Entry;
        $entrys->status = $request->input('status');
        $entrys->user_id = auth()->id(); // add this line
        $entrys->save();

        return redirect('/entry/view')->with('Success', 'Status updated!');
    }
```

Comment: you do the `with()` before the `first` then no need for `get`

Comment: after changed it i got error with `General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: sir no auth because this is admin page. or else it will fetch the admin id right? my user and admin is in the same table called `user`

Comment: no idea how you are handeling you can add any value based on your need

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'field list' (SQL: select 3 from entry)

```
Entry::with('user')->find($id);
```

> General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into entrys (status, updated_at, created_at) values (Received, 2020-09-16 12:03:08, 2020-09-16 12:03:08))

This is because you don't set the `user_id` column in your update method.

`$entrys->user_id = $request->input('user_id') // The user who gets updated`